# What is a meaning of 予約 on the washing machine?

Tags: pragmatics

According to [JMDict](http://tangorin.com/general/%E4%BA%88%E7%B4%84) 予約 is translated as

1. reservation;  appointment;  booking;  advance order
2. contract;  subscription;  pledge

None of the meanings above seem to make sense to one of the function labels on a washing machine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Japanese washing machines the 予約 is designed to set a timer for the washing machine to start. For example, if you don't want wet clothes to be in the machine while you're at work you can put clothing in there, set a 予約 timer for a an hour before you return and then it won't start the cycle until then.

Comment: In this case can it be translated as "Schedule"?

Comment: @user1602 It's a hard one to translate directly. I would hesitate to 'schedule' because it's a timer and not usually for an absolute time but for your purposes that might be the best way to translate it. Like a "scheduled wash" or something.

Comment: In this context (and *only* this context) I would probably translate it as "delay start".

Comment: @Blavius I like that much better. Thank you.

Comment: Rikaichan also gives "programming (e. g. a device), setting (e. g. a timer)".